# Alternative to seaborn pairplot to visualize dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, visualization

I have a fairly large pandas data frame((4000, 103) and for smaller dataframes I love using pairplot to visually see patterns in my data. But for my larger dataset the same command runs for hour+ with no output.

Is there an alternative tool to get the same outcome or a way to speed up the command? I tried to use the sample option on pandas to reduce the dataset but it still takes over a hour with no outcome.

```
dfSample = myData.sample(100) # make dataset smaller
sns.pairplot(dfSample, diag_kind="hist")
```

Comment: With 103 columns, pairplot will need to display 103^2 individual panels! Much two big... You could consider looking at a few columns only?

Comment: @FChm Going to sound horrible but, is there a lazy way to do this vs individually selecting columns?  I'm creating clusters of my data and historically used this approach to ensure there was some kind of pattern to my clusters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should sample from colums, so replace your first line by

```
dfSample=myData.sample(10, axis=1).
```

And live happy.